# Android - Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException caused by java.lang.SecurityException on Percel.java

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am receiving a lot of crash report as following:

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException caused by java.lang.SecurityException`

Stack trace:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/file from pid=28628, uid=10263 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderProxy.java:418)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:809)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:759)
   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:68)
   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:45)
   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:319)
   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:73)
   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have declared `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions on the manifest file and took permission from the user at runtime. What else am I missing?

**Note**: the task was running asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to your android manifest file or ask permission (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) from user before reading external storage.